# Making Text field empty when clicking on it (Prototype Framework of Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, dom-events, javascript-framework

That's my input field. I want to make value of it empty when I click it. How can I do this by using prototype framework of Javascript ?

```
<input name="ctl0$txtSearch" type="text" value="Quick Search" id="ctl0_txtSearch" class="MainSearchBar" />
```

Actually I am using PRADO. So the html tag to create input is

```
   <com:TTextBox Id="txtSearch" Text="Quick Search"  CssClass="MainSearchBar"  />
```

And it has no onclick attr to handle Javascript.

Comment: I don't understand if you can use js alone or not: "of javascript ?" Did you mean prototype OR Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick doesn't respond to keyboard events such as being 'tabbed' into. It would be more advisable to use onFocus for this. And to complement the operation also use onBlur.

```
   <com:TTextBox Id="txtSearch" Text="Quick Search"  CssClass="MainSearchBar"
       Attributes.onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';"
       Attributes.onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue;"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a place where you can also customize your text field behavior (clearing the field but also adding css...) try this code:

```
$('ctl0_txtSearch').observe('click', respondToClick);

function respondToClick(event) {
  var element = event.element();
  element.clear();
  // ... do more customization here
}
```

JS alone is enough to clear the field by just using the `onClick="javascript:this.value=''"` attribute of the input field itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <input name="ctl0$txtSearch" type="text" value="Quick Search" id="ctl0_txtSearch" 

class="MainSearchBar" onClick="javascript:ctl0_txtSearch.value='';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<input name="ctl0$txtSearch" type="text" value="Quick Search" id="ctl0_txtSearch" class="MainSearchBar" onclick="this.value = '';" />
```